# How to remove the spacing between the line and the content?

Tags: wordpress

Working on the latest Wordpress Project - couldn't find a way to remove the spacing between the line and the post.

`<h1>` was removed already, leaving the page with nothing but the content.

I've tried to dig in the code and altering a few commands but didn't find the solution so I'm addressing this site.

**Theme:** Decode, version 2.7.6

**Visual thing:**
[image]

Will provide the actual code if needed.

Comment: Here, we work with actual code, show it always. Check the guides [About] and [ask] to better pose your Questions. And welcome!

Comment: You should probably learn to use your browsers developer tools. In Chrome for example press Ctrl+Shift+C and hover over the element - it will show the size of the element itself as well as the applied margin and padding on all sides. From there you can dig for the actual style which defines this.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the title/content in question has a CSS styling with margin or paddings.

You should most likely change your themes CSS files to fix this.

[CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp) define how we display HTML.